# How to get a property value using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos;
fieldInfos = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

What I am trying to do is get the value of one of my properties of the current instantiated instance at runtime using reflection. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want a property, don't look at the fields. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @JacobKrall -- its an auto property actually, which I believe the compiler creates a backing field to implement the property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var value = (string)GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(this, null);
```

Answer (score 22):

Try the [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) method, it should get you the property, instead of fields.

To retrieve the value, do something like this:

```
object foo = ...;
object propertyValue = foo.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(foo, null);
```

This is using GetProperty, which returns just one PropertyInfo object, rather than an array of them. We then call GetValue, which takes a parameter of the object to retrieve the value from (the PropertyInfo is specific to the type, not the instance). The second parameter to GetValue is an array of indexers, for index properties, and I'm assuming the property you're interested in isn't an indexed property. (An indexed property is what lets you do `list[14]` to retrieve the 14th element of a list.)

Comment: I think OP is interested in one property in particular, and that function alone will not get the value.