# C# How to programmatically build property name

Tags: c#

I have an object called "Agent". Agent has among others, 10 properties named lab1 thru lab10. I need to assign these properties to text boxes on a form txtFieldLabel1 thru txtFieldLabel10. In the example below the left side of the operator in the loop is fine. I can't figure out the right side. I need to dynamically build the property name based on the index of the loop. This seems it should be fairly simple and similar to the left side of the operator.

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            tlp.Controls["txtFieldLabel" + i.ToString()].Text = Agent.lab + i.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: post what Agent is, the class I mean

Comment: You need to use reflection. Look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338018/how-to-get-a-property-value-using-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Agent.GetType().GetProperty("lab" + i).GetValue(Agent, null);
```

That will get the value of the property that, using reflection, is defined as `labX`, where `X` is the value of `i`.

*Edit: changed to `GetValue(Agent, null)` instead of `GetValue(Agent)`, as the overload for the single object parameter was introduced in .NET 4.5.*

Comment: While I like the simplicity of this answer and the similar one below, I get an error "No Overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: I changed to ".GetValue(Agent, null)" and it works great!

Comment: @MarkClark `GetValue(Object)` overload was introduced in .NET 4.5.  I have changed my answer to reflect the pre-4.5 next-best overload of `GetValue(Object, Object[])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection as others mentioned, but it would be easier if you created `Dictionary<int, string>` inside your `Agent` class and define those `KeyValuePairs` with keys from 1 to 10 and desirable values corresponding to those keys. Here is an example:

```
public class Agent
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Lab = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public Agent()
    {
        this.Lab.Add(1, "Value 1");
        this.Lab.Add(2, "Value 2");
        this.Lab.Add(3, "Value 3");

        // ...

        this.Lab.Add(10, "Value 10");
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
var agent = new Agent();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    tlp.Controls["txtFieldLabel" + i].Text = agent.Lab[i];
```

Comment: Sorry, can't change Agent...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the properties' values using reflection:

```
var agent = new Agent();
//...
var value = agent.GetType().GetProperty("lab" + i).GetValue(agent);
```

(Note: `Agent` is the class-name, while `agent` is the variable/instance)

---

Another (better/cleaner?) solution might be to implement the lab-properties as an array or `List<string>`, e.g:

```
class Agent {
    public List<string> Labs {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could iterate over all Labs:

```
for (var i=0; i<agent.Labs.Count; i++) {
    tlp.Controls["txtFieldLabel" + (i+1)].Text =
        agent.Labs[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This seems it should be fairly simple and similar to the left side of the operator.

It's not simple at all; you can do it using [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx), but that's pretty advanced programming.

I suspect there are more meaningful property names available to you than `lab1`, `lab2`, etc. and **strongly** recommend you use them. Anyone who has to come back to this code in a few months will be grateful.

Comment: Using Reflection is not that difficult. Unfortunately lab1-10 is as descriptive as they get.