# Get the highest value of property in Class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the highest number of all propreties in my class:

```
public class aClass{ 

        public int PropA{ get; set; } = 1;
        public int PropB{ get; set; } = 18;
        public int PropC{ get; set; } = 25; 
}
```

Here's my code:

```
public int GetMaxConfiguratableColumns()
        {
            int _HighestNumber = 0;
            PropertyInfo[] _Info = this.GetType().GetProperties(); 
            foreach(PropertyInfo _PropretyInfo in _Info)
            {
                //I'm lost here!!!!!!!
            }
            return _HighestNumber;
        }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: does it have to use reflection? or would a different approach be acceptable?

Comment: What do you mean by highest number of properties? What does `_Info` contain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp). Also [How to get a property value using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338018/how-to-get-a-property-value-using-reflection).

Comment: If you use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, instead of statically coding properties, you can count the keys.

Comment: I'm trying to get the number 25 (highest property)

Comment: @Jasen: You beat me to it. Code smell...

Comment: I'd still use a dictionary and search for the highest value. You can then easily find the related key.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to use reflection, might I suggest something like this?

```
public class aClass
{
    public int PropA { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PropB { get; set; } = 18;
    public int PropC { get; set; } = 25;

    public int GetMaxConfiguratableColumns()
    {
        return new List<int> {this.PropA, this.PropB, this.PropC}.Max();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `_PropretyInfo.GetValue(myObject)` to get the value of your current property then store it in temp variable and iterate and compare the temp value with the rest

Answer (score 0):

I think you would wind up with something like this:

```
        int highestNumber = 0;      

        PropertyInfo[] info = this.GetType().GetProperties(); 
        foreach(PropertyInfo propInfo in info)
        {
            if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
                int propValue = (int)(propInfo.GetValue(this, null));
                if (propValue > highestNumber) {
                    highestNumber = propValue;
                }
            }
        }

        return highestNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer:

```
 public int GetMaxConfiguratableColumns()
        {
            PaymentHeader PaymentHeader = new PaymentHeader();
            int max = typeof(PaymentHeader)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Select(x => (int)x.GetValue(PaymentHeader)).Max();

            return max;
        }
```

To whoever needs this.